# Huge discrepancy between Revenue and Product Revenue

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

I'm seeing a big difference between the reported Revenue and the Product Revenue on transactions. For example, this is what I see for Revenue for a transaction:

[image: Product Revenue]

And this is the (correct) amount that shows up when I click into that Transaction ID.

[image: Product Revenue]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Revenue of the transaction and the Product Revenue are two differents metrics and comes from 2 differents parts of the code. Let me explain you what is maybe happening.

This is the transaction code for the enhanced ecommerce, but it can happens in all the versions of the ecommerce snippet

```
ga('ec:addProduct', {               // Provide product details in an productFieldObject.
  'id': 'P12345',                   // Product ID (string).
  'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt', // Product name (string).
  'category': 'Apparel',            // Product category (string).
  'brand': 'Google',                // Product brand (string).
  'variant': 'black',               // Product variant (string).
  'price': '29.20',                 // Product price (currency).  <-- UnitPrice
  'coupon': 'APPARELSALE',          // Product coupon (string).  
  'quantity': 1                     // Product quantity (number). <--Quantity
});

ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {          // Transaction details are provided in an actionFieldObject.
  'id': 'T12345',                         // (Required) Transaction id (string).
  'affiliation': 'Google Store - Online', // Affiliation (string).
  'revenue': '37.39',                     // Revenue (currency). <<- Revenue
  'tax': '2.85',                          // Tax (currency).
  'shipping': '5.34',                     // Shipping (currency).
  'coupon': 'SUMMER2013'                  // Transaction coupon (string).
});
```

The product Revenue is based on the multiplication of the Quantity * UnitPrice (calculated in each transaction) and the Transaction Revenue belongs to the 'purchase' object.

Google Analytics dosent matter any logic, for example, you can have in one transaction a product price of $99.99 with Quantity of 2 and in the same transaction declarate the reveue as $2 and it's ok for Analytics. And we know that is not right.

So, you need to make that number match, The common mistakes here are:

Transactions apply Discount -> Sum of product dont have discount applied

Transactions don't apply Discount -> Sum of product have discount applied

Transaction is A -> Sum of Product is C

Comment: Congrats for the detailed answer. One thing to note is that in the real world it is OK to have an item revenue of 2*99.99 and a purchase value of only $2: coupons/discounts or any other promotion could have been used.

Answer (score 2):

Google does not add product values up - instead the product revenue and the transaction revenue is passed to GA via different variables in the tracking code, and the reports show the respective variable values.

So I guess somebody passed in the wrong value (I vaguely suspect a wrong decimal separator). You need to check your transaction code.